# Change accessory in unvisible cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How to specify UITableViewCellAccessoryNone in cell is not visible? 
If I write:

```
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

It does not help, the marker remains.

Comment: It might not matter, but where are you making that assignment? What method?

Comment: @stevesliva in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: You should always pair this call with a change to your backing view model. That way the state of the accessory view will be retained if the cell is scrolled off-screen or the table is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The Cell for Row at index path will not return the exact cell object rendered on the screen.
Try to update your model object and reload the corresponding row. Handle the accessory type none in `cellForRowAtIndexpath`.

Answer (score 0):

First, update the state of the item in your model. Then, Only update the cell itself if it is already onscreen (`[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index]` returns a cell, instead of `nil`). If it *does* return nil, you have nothing more to do. The cell is not on screen, so assuming your datasource method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is set up to correctly set the accessory type based on the data source, the cell will be created correctly the next time it is scrolled onto the screen.